# Add column to the right - HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I just started to learn programming in PHP. So i got an old script from a friend where i can learn on and got the following question.

The scripts contains a menu on the left wich is this code:

```
<td width="125" align="left" valign="top" class="left_nav"><table width="125" border="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="left_nav_inner">
```

**Actions:**

- test.

Can someone help me how to put the column on the right?

This is the class left_nav

```
.left_nav {
    background: #333;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 0px solid #000000;
    border-top: 0px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;       
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #999999;
    width: 125px;`
}
```

Comment: Your HTML doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Your html is incomplete.What you should do is provide more source code. Apparently you have a nested table inside another tables cell.In your case it would be better to swap the contents of the tds(cells).

Comment: This has nothing to do with javascript or PHP. it's purely html/css

Comment: Ok i will post the code

Comment: The table won't work. There is IMPORTANT code missing. Post the rest of the table and then maybe we might be able to help you!

Comment: Is this a layout? Also why is there a table in a table?

Comment: Where is your code to actually add the column?  That should be either PHP or JavaScript, as highlighted by Marc B.  Your table is incomplete and it's not really best practice to nest tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change css:

```
.left_nav {
    position:absolute;
    right: 0px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: #333;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 0px solid #000000;
    border-top: 0px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;       
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #999999;
    width: 125px;

}
```

See Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/HjYR9/

Comment: Nice!And how to put it a few enters down?

Answer (score 0):

1. First this has nothing to  with php
2. Second your html is incomplete
   or its just wrong.

But if you want a object in the right corner of your screen use this.

```
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
```

visit this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) link if you want to find more info about it

Comment: And how to put it a few enters down?

Comment: change  top to a bigger value

Comment: its better to change top: 50px; then using margin-top its redundant